# Android: Boolean function if network state change

Tags: android

How to determine if network state changed since last check?
What I need is a simple boolean function, which will:

-return true if network state changed 
-false if not,

I have a code which write data about network connections to file it runs on background after mobile is started, and I need to write data to file only when network status was changed.

For example 
I started mobile, I connected to wifi make one write to file,
I dont do nothing with mobile for 30 minutes, nothing will be written,
then I switch wifi off, make another one write to file.

Comment: Please take a look at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Comment: Thanks, everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create BroadcastReceiver and override `onReceive` method. Here is more information http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm